# Ag-grid row drag drop - Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

On one of our react website we implemented ag-grid and have row grouping and row dragging functionality enabled.

While trying to drag a row from group 1 to group 50 (far away group) in which auto dragging scrolling occurs then i am getting error generated in Aggrid js file.
Below is the stack trace from console -

`ag-grid-community.cjs.js:26975 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at RowDragFeature.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.cjs.js.RowDragFeature.stopDragging (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:26975)
at RowDragFeature.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.cjs.js.RowDragFeature.onDragStop (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:26966)
at DragAndDropService.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.cjs.js.DragAndDropService.onDragStop (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:17368)
at DragService.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.cjs.js.DragService.onUpCommon (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:31179)
at DragService.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.cjs.js.DragService.onMouseUp (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:31174)
at HTMLDocument.mouseUpEvent (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:31074)`

Please suggest on how should i proceed / fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug in the default handlers that ag-grid provides. I'm also getting this on a project I started today. You can supply your own handlers for all of the props, which solved the problem for me.

I ran into this for grid to grid, and did the following. If you're using in-grid dragging, you should be able to do something similar, though it looks like the props have different names (such as onDragEnd instead of onDragStop). This assumes that you're managing state yourself and therefore taking action on dragEnd, etc.

Example for grid to grid dragging:

```
const dropZoneParams = {
  onDragging: (args) => console.log('onDragging', {...args}),
  onDragEnter: (args) =>
    console.log('onDragEnter', {...args}),
  onDragLeave: (args) =>
    console.log('onDragLeave', {...args}),
  onDragStop: (args) => console.log('onDragStop', {...args}),
  getContainer: params.api.getRowDropZoneParams().getContainer,
}
```

Comment: i tried this and didnt work, until internal stopdragging is completed these methods are not invoked.
I am moving the rows within same grid so i shouldn't need to add dropZoneParams.

The issue seems to be that under getRowNodes method
there is a  call to
this.isFromThisGrid(draggingEvent)

which return "false", should be true because row is from same grid.

Comment: Have you tried to override the event handlers for the in-grid dragging (rather than adding a dropzone)?

Comment: yes, and that gets called after processing from ag-grid js is done.

Comment: This happened to me, probably because my onDragging fn caused a redraw of some table cells, which caused the event source to no longer be part of the grid. Setting the fn to just console.log showed this was the case. Scrolling might cause similar behavior (row dragged is no longer visible therefore isFromGrid returns false).